# DB2 - ALTER table ADD column with unique default value (UUID)

Tags: database, function, db2, uuid, alter-table

I need to update an existing table by adding a new column with default value as UUID and datatype as VARCHAR(255).

I tried to achieved it by writing a function as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION UUID_FUNC()
     RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
     LANGUAGE SQL 
     BEGIN ATOMIC
     DECLARE UUID VARCHAR(4000);
     SET UUID = (SELECT TRIM(CHAR(HEX(GENERATE_UNIQUE()))) from sysibm.sysdummy1);
     RETURN UUID;
END
```

And used it in the query as:

```
ALTER TABLE <Table-name> 
    ADD ID_VALUE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID_FUNC())
```

Got following error when executing the above query:

```
SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "DEFAULT" was found following "ARCHAR(255) NOT NULL".  
Expected tokens may include:  "CHECK".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.59.81
```

What is the correct format for calling custom defined functions in ALTER query or any suggestions to achieve the above requirement is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can’t specify a function name in the `DEFAULT` clause. Check the `Default-values` possible options in the [CREATE TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) statement. Is it really necessarily to use `varchar(255)` and `generate_unique`? Why not to use, let’s say, generated column of some numeric (int/bigint/decimal) data type?

Comment: platform & version of Db2 should be mentioned, though i don't think it would make a difference in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve it in following way:

```
ALTER TABLE <Table-name> ADD ID_VALUE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';

UPDATE <Table-name> SET ID_VALUE=(hex(GENERATE_UNIQUE())) WHERE ID_VALUE='0';
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do this via a trigger, rather than as a generated expression.  Given the DDL:

```
create or replace function your.uuid_func()
   returns char(26)
   language sql
   not deterministic
   return values(hex(generate_unique()));

create table your.table (
   c1 int not null,
   c2 char(26) not null
);
```

You can create the trigger:

```
create trigger set_uuid
   before insert on your.table
   referencing new as n
   for each row
   when (n.id_value is null)
      set n.id_value = your.uuid_func();
```

Then the insert:

```
—- You can insert a normal string:
insert into your.table (c1, c2)
   values (1, ‘anything’);


—- Or, if you don’t provide a value for c2, it will be set
—- to the value of UUID_FUNC():

insert into your.table (c1) 
    values (2);
```

Results:

```
select * from your.table;

C1          C2                        
----------- --------------------------
          1 anything                     
          2 20200111154913255440000000
```

Answer (score -1):

ALTER TABLE  ADD ID_VALUE AS (UUID_FUNC());

For accessing existing field values,
ALTER TABLE  ADD ID_VALUE AS (UUID_FUNC([field_name]));

Comment: It is not working, get following error when running this query - ```SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "ALTER TABLE ADD" was found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<create_view>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.59.81```